# Footer Floating Up Into Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap columns to lay out my administration page and I'm having some trouble getting the footer to stay at the bottom. For some reason, the footer keeps flying up into the bottom of the second column instead of saying below the columns, despite not being included in the column structure. Why might this be happening?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Administration</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


    <link href="/Content/Administration.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Football Pool 2014</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Rules">Rules</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="/Results">Results</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/SelectPerson?w=False">Weekly Picks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/SelectPerson?w=True">Winners Pool</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form action="/Account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="xxx" />    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/Administration">Administration</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="/Account/Manage" title="Manage">Hello User!</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">




<h2>Administration</h2>

<div>

</div>

<div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="adminButton" href="/Home/CreatePerson">Create Person</a>
        <a class="adminButton" href="/Administration/UpdateOrDeletePerson">Update or Delete Person</a>
        <a class="adminButton" href="/Administration/ManageResults">Manage Results</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <a class="adminButton" href="/Administration/UpdateWeeklyPicks">Manage Weekly Picks</a>
        <a class="adminButton" href="/Administration/UpdateWinnersPicks">Manage Winners Picks</a>
    </div>
</div>



        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2014 - us</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"xxx"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:123/xxx/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {

}

.adminButton
{
    display:block;
    background-color:#0072C6;
    padding:30px;
    width:300px;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20pt;
    margin:1px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:'Segoe UI Light';
}
.adminButton:hover
{
    background-color:#1E82CC;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
.adminButton:active
{
    background-color:#212121;
}
```

Comment: You are missing your `<div class="row">....</div>` for those columns. Since they are floated and there is no `clear` on the footer that's why it's going up. (that's my guess since there is no jsfiddle :) )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 and Sticky Footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070813/bootstrap-3-and-sticky-footer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed to add `row` check [this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/wBytI)

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I think drip is correct. Check out the Bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) on grids. The order should be container > row > column, though the column class is unneeded if you just want a single full width column. This will work:

```
<div class="row">
    <footer>
    <hr />
    <p>&copy; 2014 - us</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Curious, why did you use the "xs" columns?

Comment: Yeah now that I'm reading the Grid [Examples](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) it says no grid class is technically needed if you want a single full width column on all device sizes. So only if you wanted a mix of sizes as in `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">`A column that's full width on extra small devices, 1/2 width on small devices, and 2/3 width on medium devices`</div>` you'd add in the col-xs-12. I've updated my answer accordingly.